# filter olap pivot table based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, olap

The following code is working:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields( _
    "[Cost Center].[Cost Center].[Cost Center L4]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Cost Center].[Cost Center].[Cost Center L4].&[0130]")
```

But if I'm trying to change it to variance, I'm getting an error:

```
Dim NewCat As String
NewCat = Range("A1").Value
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields( _
    "[Cost Center].[Cost Center].[Cost Center L4]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Cost Center].[Cost Center].[Cost Center L4].&["&(NewCat)&"]")
```

Please advise how can I filter it by a value from cell A1

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `NewCat`? Any chance it is `130`, not `0130`? Try using `Format(Newcat, "0000")`.

Comment: Thanks! it's working great